# mysql php cpu abuse

Tags: mysql, cpu, vps

I have a site in shared plan with a mysql database. The database has a table with ~300000 rows. The table is ~250mb. In every page I call query:

```
select * from table order by added limit 0,30
```

In every row is field with 400 characters code which I need. Basically I need all fields.
Until few days ago everything is ok but slow with 500 visitors/day. Now my site is down because I have an alert about cpu abuse(with 1000 visitors/day). In my local server all goes very well with no big cpu usage (~10%).

What can I do to make best performance for my queries?

If I go to VPS plan everything will be ok or the real problem is my table?

Answer (score 0):

Is "added" field indexed? MySQL will scan whole table every time if the table is not indexed by the field in ORDER BY.  By indexing your table

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX `added` (`added`);
```

you'll dramatically reduce cpu usage.

Comment: yes. added is indexed. also the table is myisam, and I use pdo to execute queries.

Comment: I run explain in my local server and host server and I have very good times.